# extraer elemento de una lista como tipo string

Tags: python, lista

AL extraer un elemento de mi lista de criptomonedas se me muestra de la siguiente forma:

['LOKI']

mi interes seria recibir solo LOKI, sin apostrofe, corchetes, ni espacios. Ya que mi
interes es agregarle un par de esa moneda. Ejemplo USDT.

para que una variable termine LOKI-USDT

Seria esto posible? gracias por cualquier ayuda u opinion que me puedan aportar

acabo de probar esta manera y me funciona, a veces:

```
list_difference = []

StrL = "".join(list_difference )


for element in normal_coin:
    if element not in old_coin:
        list_difference.append(element)

print(StrL)
```

con esa lista en especifico "list_difference" no me funciona, solo me imprime un valor vacio, mientras que en "old_coin" y "normal_coin"(dos listas que comparo), funciona sin problemas

Comment: Si no muestras los datos de entrada cualquier respuesta es pura especulación.

Answer (score 0):

no por que, ni nada por el estilo, pero saque de esta forma la diferencia entre las listas y me funciono bien a la hora de covertirla a un string:

```
list_difference = [element for element in normal_coin if element not in old_coin]

StrL1 = ''.join(list_difference)

USD='USDT'

print(StrL1+'-'+USD)
print(list_difference)
```

a lo que me devolvio:

```
LOKI-USDT
['LOKI']
```

si alguien sabe el por que de una forma me devolvia un valor invisible y de esta otra manera no se lo agradeceria, espero que a alguien le ayude mi solucion